# My discord bot isn't coming online - discord v13

Tags: node.js, discord, bots

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh1RU.png)this bot has been working for about 2 weeks and suddenly it wont go online? The terminal isn't spitting out any errors at all. It isn't even logging the ready message. I'm quite new to this so if you do need any further information just let me know :)

edit:: I've restored the token a few times and reinvited the bot myself but that isn't fixing it :/

The client.js file:

```
const {Client, Intents, Collection } = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config();
const client = new Client ({intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]});
const fs = require('fs');
client.commands = new Collection();

const functions = fs.readdirSync("./src/functions").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync("./src/events").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync("./src/commands");

(async () => {
    for(file of functions){
        require(`./functions/${file}`)(client);
    }
    client.handleEvents(eventFiles, "./src/events");
    client.handleCommands(commandFolders, "./src/commands");
    client.on("ready", () => {
        client.user.setActivity('discord.js', { type: 'WATCHING' });  
    });
    client.login(process.env.token);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of code, you are making an async anonymous function. However, you are just defining it. You are not calling it! That means that none of your commands nor events are being loaded. In order to make them load, you must call the function.

```js
(async () => {
    // your loader code here
    client.login(process.env.token);
    // notice the extra () here. That is calling the function.
})();
```